# AMD Modules - Where does it load in this example?

Tags: javascript, amd

I have a complicated situation that involves scripts being loaded from different sources but to understand my problem I think it will be easier if I ask a simple question regarding AMD modules which I am not too familiar with.

On a site that is using AMD modules, there is a define function available.
What happens if I try to define and load a module like this:

```
define([], () => { return { thisIsMyTest: true } })
```

How do I know get access to that module I just defined?

I tried looking within **require._defined**

But I couldn't see it (I could have missed it too as I am not sure what name to look for).

The script that wants to access that object is not a AMD compatible script but I have control over that aspect so I am happy to write code for it.

Now to add some more clarify to the problem, I have a script that loads on a site (which I have no control over), my script loads another external script remotely (which I don't have any control over). This external script in normal cases exposes itself as a variable on the Window object, however it supports AMD modules and this said site uses AMD, so in this case this external script uses the define method of loading and I can't figure out how to get access to it.

Update:

Here is my snippet of code that loads my external library:

```
const libScript = document.createElement('script');
libScript.type = 'text/javascript';
libScript.src = '//some/3rdparty/lib.js'; // source 
libScript.onload = () => {  
  // Use the library that normally exists on window.Lib  
  // However libScript in this site loads using AMD  
  // and window.Lib doesn't exist for sites that use AMD  
  // Other non AMD sites work fine. 
}; 
document.head.appendChild(libScript);
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. If you need to require a remote script with AMD, you can totally do it. But you will need a `require` at some point. Is your main script (the one that needs to load your AMD module) a AMD main script?

Comment: No my main script is not AMD, it is a normal script but the script I load is a 3rd party library which I have to load remote (using a dynamic script tag) but the site I get loaded on uses AMD and my this library detects it so it changes from the normal window object variable loading to being a AMD module that literally loads like the above code 'define([], factory)'. So how do I load this module in my normal script, what is the name I use in require?

Comment: I'm going to need more code than what you provided. Can you post your HTML document and your main script?

Comment: My script is quite big, I added the loading part of the external library if it helps